# Solr database with multiple schema

Tags: solr

My solr db has multiple schema as below,

```
***Part of Schema 1***
<field1>
<field2>
<field3>
<field4>
<field5>

***Part of Schema 2***
<field6>
<field7>
<field8>
```

When I do a `q = *:*`, I get `<field6>`,`<field7>` and `<field8>` but not the remaining fields..
I am able to select fields 1-5 only when `field1:'value'` in the q object.

Is there a way to know that 6-8 is part of schema-2 and 1-5 is part of schema-1

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your search handler (like (e)DISMAX) you can define the default search fields. 
Or you can use the `qf=` Parameter to define the fields, you like to search in: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qf_.28Query_Fields.29

If you like to separate your DB schema in solr, so that fields from schema-1 does not know the fields from schema-2, you can use 2 different solr cores: one for each schema.

> Is there a way to know that 6-8 is part of schema-2 and 1-5 is part of schema-1

As far as i know, Solr does not support DB schemas. A field insight solr is a field. There is no way to add additional (meta) informations, where this field is coming from. So you will not be able to filter your queries depending on there origin - except by defining the Query fields or by separating schemas in cores or something like that.